# Dope Sheet Key Automation/Effects/Preset

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I have all this elements that are going down on the animation I would like to automate the all the keys one after another so that they follow a standard of creating the elements one after the another:
[image]

There´s any kind wihout using some addon?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written this script to shift all the keyframes at once.

1. Select the objects
2. Open the script in the Text Edit
3. Set the amount of frames, eg: step(10)
4. Run script (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

---

```
import bpy

def shift(step):
    interval = 0.0
    for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        interval += step
        if object.animation_data !=  None:
            fcurves = object.animation_data.action.fcurves
            for curve in fcurves:
                keyframepoints = curve.keyframe_points
                for point in keyframepoints:
                    point.co.x += interval 
                    point.handle_left.x += interval
                    point.handle_right.x += interval
                    
                
shift(10)
```

---

The script will loop through the fcurves of the selected objects and will increment the x value of each point.

### Caveat:

1. the script doesn't allow to set the order of the objects.
2. the script will shift ALL the keyframes

[image]

Comment: Damn m8 wIth all respect! your devilish!